# Functions for dynamic elements

Tags: c#, wpf, function, dynamic

I have created a set of dynamic elements during run time. How do I define and declare functions for them beforehand?

i.e. I will be creating a set of 25 buttons during execution, and assigning various attribute values to each one of them.

How do I, say, add onclick events for such elements, i.e. buttons?

Declaring and defining them before 'compiling' them, would result in error? Won't it?

Comment: You can add action handlers to Controls at any point during program execution. You probably want to use Nacereddine's second method because it's easier to apply to all 25 buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
yourButton.Click += (o, args) =>
            {
                // Code goes here...
            };
```

or create a method for the click event :

```
yourButton.Click += yourButton_Click;

private void yourButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    // Code goes here...
}
```

you can do this for any even not just the `Click` one.